# Paypal code's color scheme

Tags: sublimetext3, color-scheme

Is there a method to extract the code's color scheme from paypal code expamples and place it in sublime text?
Here is a link: [Paypal link](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to manually do it. You can use this [Sublime Text Color Scheme Generator](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai). In the Paypal window, you can use developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + C if you're using Chrome) and click on the words to see the exact color value, and then just use those in the color scheme generator.

EDIT: Please take a look at @sergioFC's answer, he gave an easier way of finding all the color values.

Answer (score 2):

That page is made using [Groc](https://github.com/nevir/groc), that put comments next to code in a beautiful way. Groc seems to use two projects that I have used before: [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) and maybe [pygments](http://pygments.org/), to highlight the code, but they don't use any of the default stylesheets, I think they use their own stylesheet.

**Inside the Groc project you can see this [sass file](https://github.com/nevir/groc/blob/master/lib/styles/default/_codestyles-pygments.sass) which contains almost all the info you need (color for variables, strings, keywords, etc.)** to manually add the values to a custom color scheme. In addition [Groc  style documentation](http://nevir.github.io/groc/styles/default/style.html) shows other useful values of the Color Scheme such as the background. You can get other values inspecting DOM.

Comment: @LucaPunes It would be great if you post the resulting color scheme

Comment: Sure, as soon as I can